# Can i use myanmar unicode font in Solaris?

Tags: solaris

I can not see myanmar font in Solaris.I want to use zawgyi font in solaris.
Can i use Zaw gyi font of Myanmar font(Burma) in Solaris?.Please answer me.

Comment: Solaris supports fonts in the TrueType, OpenType, PostScript Type 1, PCF & BDF formats (all via standard FreeType & X.Org libraries).   What format is "zawgyi" font in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zawgyi font can be installed in Solaris platform but you can only use the zawgyi keyboard through Xorgcfg utility.

If your Zawgyi texts are properly encoded in UTF-8 or AL16UTF16, it should not be problem.